# Why do I have to export a forward declaration or forward declare a class before the export module clause in a module interface unit to make it work?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, c++-modules

Consider this program:

MyType1.ixx:

```
export module MyType1;

namespace MyNamespace {
    class MyType2;

    export class MyType1 {
    public:
        MyType1(MyType2* MyType2);
        void Print();
    private:
        MyType2* MyType2Instance{};
    };
}
```

Module1.cpp:

```
module MyType1;

import <iostream>;

import MyType2;

namespace MyNamespace {
    MyType1::MyType1(MyType2* MyType2) {
        MyType2->Print();
    }

    void MyType1::Print() {
        std::cout << "Hello MyType1\n";
        MyType2Instance->Print();
    };
}
```

MyType2.ixx:

```
export module MyType2;

import <iostream>;

namespace MyNamespace {
    export class MyType2 {
    public:
        void Print() {
            std::cout << "Hello MyType2\n";
        }
    };
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
import MyType1;
import MyType2;

using namespace MyNamespace;

void main() {
    MyType2 MyType2{};
    MyType1 MyType1(&MyType2);
    MyType1.Print();
    MyType2.Print();
}
```

Doing this gets me an error in Visual Studio: `Error C2665 'MyNamespace::MyType1::MyType1': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types`.

[image]

One solution is to also export the forward-declared class MyType2 in MyType1.ixx:

```
export module MyType1;

namespace MyNamespace {
    export class MyType2;

    export class MyType1 {
    public:
        MyType1(MyType2* MyType2);
    private:
        MyType2* MyType2Intance{};
    };
}
```

The output:
[image]

Another solution is to forward-declare the MyType2 class before the `export module MyType1` line:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    class MyType2;
}

export module MyType1;

namespace MyNamespace {
    export class MyType1 {
    public:
        MyType1(MyType2* MyType2);
    private:
        MyType2* MyType2Intance{};
    };
}
```

The question is why does this work and how does this work, and why a more brain-friendly and intuitive solution of just forward-declaring the class inside the module doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do doesn't really make sense. And the fact that you have decided to name your modules the same as your classes makes it extremely difficult to explain what's going on (please stop doing this; modules should not be single-classes in size. There's no point in making modules that small).

In any case, the principle issue is that, if you put a declaration in a module, the module system thinks that you *mean it*. By declaring `MyNamespace::MyType2` inside of the module `MyType1`, that means that the module system thinks that... `MyNamespace::MyType2` is *part of* `MyType1`.

Therefore, when it gets around to compiling the `MyType2` module, when it finds a class named `MyNamespace::MyType2`, it believes that this is a *different class* from the one local to the `MyType1` module.

Because it is.

Therefore, when your `main` function creates `MyNamespace::MyType2`, this is of the type from the `MyType2` module (since nobody outside of `MyType1` has access to the `MyType1`'s non-exported stuff). Since this is a different type from the one used by `MyNamespace::MyType1`, the compiler cannot convert pointers to two unrelated type.

What you have is that the module `MyType1` has a dependency on the module `MyType2`. It should import `MyType2` in its primary module interface. And since you can't use `MyType1` without having a `MyType2`, it should probably `export import` it.

Or better yet... don't make these into separate modules. They can be in separate module *files*, but they should all be part of the same module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nicol. _"it believes that this is a different class from the one local to the MyType1 module"_. Then why when I do `export class MyType2;` inside the MyType1 module interface unit, it just works? If what you're saying was the case, then this solution with exporting MyType2 from MyType1 wouldn't have worked: it would believe that MyType2 class inside MyType1 module and MyType2 class inside MyType2 module are different classes and wouldn't compile just the same as before. But it does compile when I export it.

Comment: @KulaGGin: it is either ill-formed/NDR due to conflicting names from different modules (aka: it's wrong, but compilers don't have to catch and error on it), or the first name imported wins. Either way, I suspect that if you try to use the class `MyType2` as something other than a pointer (in a way inconsistent with a forward declaration), you'll have a problem.

Comment: _"I suspect that if you try to use the class MyType2 as something other than a pointer"_ I updated my question and actually can use MyType2 class in both: the MyType1 class and the Main.cpp that imports both modules. If I remove the `import MyType2` from the MyType1.cpp file(and the usage of the MyType2::Print function inside MyType1, of course), then I can still correctly pass MyType2 pointer to MyType1 constructor in the Main.cpp file just fine and also call MyType2::Print function inside Main.cpp(unlike when I don't export the class in MyType1 module).

Comment: So it appears everything is correctly recognized if I do `export class MyType2;` from inside `MyType1` module.